# In MS Team Adaptive Card, how do I specify the server it post to?

Tags: json, server, google-cloud-functions, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to use Action.Submit in my adaptive card to hit my Google Cloud Function.  Where do I specify where to send the submission to?  The reason I am doing this is I want to skip building a full chat server due to time constraint.

Example of Adaptive Card, no property to specify post URL:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Present a form and submit it back to the originator"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "firstName",
      "placeholder": "What is your first name?"
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "id": "lastName",
      "placeholder": "What is your last name?"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Action.Submit",
      "data": {
        "x": 13
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the Adaptive Card? Is it in a chat with your Teams app? What is the scope of the conversation? How did the Adaptive Card get there? Can you post links and screenshots?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes I can't post the detail, but the client want to be able to us MS Team as frontend without having to use Microsoft server, so I was wondering if it's possible to make REST Post from directly within MS Team to arbitrary servers, then it would be trivia to setup a simple REST endpoint in Google.

Comment: I want to help but I don't understand what you're doing so I need more information. Are you willing to answer my questions?

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: All right, would you please answer the questions I asked in my first comment? Also, is Omar's answer acceptable?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I got reassigned actually, so it's off my hand now.  If you are interested, add me on linkedin though.  We should network:  https://www.linkedin.com/in/billsoftwareengineer/

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive cards aren't developed specifically for bot service.
so working with them needs some tricks , in your case if you are trying to send a request that contain adaptive card inputs you need to know :

- when the user click the submit button the adaptive card will send a message to bot **activity handler on behalf of the user**, this message contains a **JSON object** (you can view this object by adding this line in the bot **onMessage function**.

> console.log(context.activity)

- you can get the data from this meesage by using :

> context.activity.value.firstName (to get the firstName sent by the adaptive card)

- Now you can send your request to the server i prefer using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) .